# how to use regular expressions in the middle of redirect in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Consider the snap of code in `.htaccess`.

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

ErrorDocument 404 /error-404/

Redirect 301 /day /published/?duration=day
Redirect 301 /week /published/?duration=week
Redirect 301 /month /published/?duration=month
Redirect 301 /year /published/?duration=year

Redirect 301 /trending/day /trending/?duration=day
Redirect 301 /trending/week /trending/?duration=week
Redirect 301 /trending/month /trending/?duration=month
Redirect 301 /trending/year /trending/?duration=year

Redirect 301 /new/day /new/?duration=day
Redirect 301 /new/week /new/?duration=week
Redirect 301 /new/month /new/?duration=month
Redirect 301 /new/year /new/?duration=year

Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

## Set home page
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php?con=home&task=published [L]
```

It is working well. The problem is when I try to use regular expression kinds of stuff, it is not working ...

UPDATE:

For example:
When the user tries to browse `http://example.com/month` it should redirect to `http://example.com/published/?duration=month`.

FYI, I am going to process the entire request in `index.php` ...

Can you please suggest to me some examples to FIX and minimize the above code in `.htaccess`?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please do mention in your question ef: **FROM** which url **TO** which url you want to redirect/rewrite? That will make your question more clear(Not my downvote btw), cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 it is the same domain URL redirect. so, i guess, no need to mention FROM and TO domain ...

Comment: IMHO `redirect` doesn't take query string(I may be wrong also but I don't think it supports it). Yeah asking sample links doesn't mean it should be different domain then only it helps. For example if you want to redirect link Eg: `http://localhost:80/day` TO `http://localhost:80/published/` but in backend you want it to be served by `index.php` file with certain parameters. So if you could add this kind of information then it will be more helpful, cheers.

Comment: thank you @RavinderSingh13. I am adding a few more detail ...

Comment: If you want to use regex then you must use `RedirectMatch` instead of `Redirect`

Comment: @anubhava can you please give me an example?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I did update my question. Please take a look.

Comment: Do you want an external redirect or internal rewrite (with no change in URLs)?

Comment: I want to redirect with a URL change ...

Comment: You say you have a problem with "regular expression kinds of stuff" but your example does not use or require a regex?

Comment: my bad, it did not work anything that is mentionable here ...

Comment: I would do this using RewriteRules instead of RedirectMatch (but that might be a matter of personal preference.) `RewriteRule ^(day|week|month|year)$ /published/?duration=$1 [R=302]` (Replace `302` with `301` later, when you got the whole thing fully tested & working, 302 avoids problems with caching of redirects.)

Comment: And the `trending` and `new` you could handle with one rule, using alternation in two places: `RewriteRule ^(trending|new)/(day|week|month|year)$ /$1/?duration=$2 [R=302]`